# SQL Server - Windows Active Directory users

Tags: active-directory, sql-server, domain-controller, windows-installer

I am actually using SQL server for my application. If I work with one user (Install and Update app with WIX installer) everything works good, but if I try to change me windows user account to the other user, who can work with such database, but do not have Login of the user who was installing app with publishing DB, in Logins directory in SSMS. This user uses SQL Server Authentication. Is there a way to allow users who are in the Windows Active directory in domain admin group to add them all database previlages? Thanks in advance

Comment: dba.stackexchange.com is specific for database questions.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question as "Is there a way to allow Active Directory users to access all databases with priviledges".

Yes.

You have a few different options. For example in SQL Server Management Studio, you can tick each checkbox for all databases from the user mapping interface in the login properties to grant the access. You can also create a script to iterate through all databases.

Make sure to select "SQL and Windows Authentication" in the Servers security options.